# Restore maximzed state on secondary monitor

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem about restore state of window when I maximized it on secondary monitor.
I maximized window on the not primary screen and then close.
When reopen window, it also maximized, but it is maximized on primary screen.
I want is maximized on the not primary screen (the screen display window when close).

Please help me if you know.

Note: if state of window is normal, window will be restored correct screen.

My code as below:

```
 if (ShellState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            ShellState = WindowState.Normal;
            LeftPosition = Screen.AllScreens[selectedScreen].WorkingArea.Left;
            TopPosition = Screen.AllScreens[selectedScreen].WorkingArea.Top;
            ShellHeight = Screen.AllScreens[selectedScreen].WorkingArea.Height;
            ShellWidth = Screen.AllScreens[selectedScreen].WorkingArea.Width;
            ShellState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had many problems on multi-screen systems using the standard WPF tools for storing and restoring the window state and size, as long as the screen assignment.

We endet with creating a custom behavior that uses the native WinAPI functions.
Here is the (simplified) source code of our behavior. You can use it in your application instead of the WPF tools.

You have to change the way the window placement will be stored. This can be a dependency property providing a container, a static `Properties.Settings` reference or something else. In the code below, a static `ApplicationSettings` reference is used as an example.

```
class WindowPlacementPersistenceBehavior : Behavior<Window>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.SourceInitialized += this.AssociatedObject_SourceInitialized;
        this.AssociatedObject.Closing += this.AssociatedObject_Closing;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.SourceInitialized -= this.AssociatedObject_SourceInitialized;
        this.AssociatedObject.Closing -= this.AssociatedObject_Closing;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        WINDOWPLACEMENT wp;
        NativeMethods.GetWindowPlacement(new WindowInteropHelper(this.AssociatedObject).Handle, out wp);

        // Here you can store the window placement
        ApplicationSettings.WindowPlacement = wp.ToString();
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Here you can load the window placement
        WINDOWPLACEMENT wp = WINDOWPLACEMENT.Parse(ApplicationSettings.WindowPlacement);
        if (wp.ShowCmd == NativeMethods.SW_SHOWMINIMIZED)
        {
            // Don't start in the minimized state
            wp.ShowCmd = NativeMethods.SW_SHOWNORMAL;
        }

        try
        {
            NativeMethods.SetWindowPlacement(new WindowInteropHelper(this.AssociatedObject).Handle, ref wp);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;

        public static RECT Parse(string input)
        {
            RECT result;
            string[] items = input.Split(';');
            result.Left = int.Parse(items[0]);
            result.Top = int.Parse(items[1]);
            result.Right = int.Parse(items[2]);
            result.Bottom = int.Parse(items[3]);
            return result;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Left + ";" + this.Top + ";" + this.Right + ";" + this.Bottom;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public static POINT Parse(string input)
        {
            POINT result;
            string[] items = input.Split(';');
            result.X = int.Parse(items[0]);
            result.Y = int.Parse(items[1]);
            return result;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.X + ";" + this.Y;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
    {
        public int Length;
        public int Flags;
        public int ShowCmd;
        public POINT MinPosition;
        public POINT MaxPosition;
        public RECT NormalPosition;

        public static WINDOWPLACEMENT Parse(string input)
        {
            WINDOWPLACEMENT result = default(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
            result.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT));
            try
            {
                string[] items = input.Split('/');
                result.Flags = int.Parse(items[0]);
                result.ShowCmd = int.Parse(items[1]);
                result.MinPosition = POINT.Parse(items[2]);
                result.MaxPosition = POINT.Parse(items[3]);
                result.NormalPosition = RECT.Parse(items[4]);
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            return result;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Flags + "/" + this.ShowCmd + "/" + this.MinPosition.ToString() + "/" + this.MaxPosition.ToString() + "/" + this.NormalPosition.ToString();
        }
    }

    private static class NativeMethods
    {
        public const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        public const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, [In] ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, [Out] out WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);
    }
}
```

To use this behavior, just add it to your window in XAML:

```
<Window
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <v:WindowPlacementPersistenceBehavior />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Window>
```